# Date Conversion from mysql to php

Tags: php, mysql, date-format, date-formatting

I get the data from database to html page as

```
     <?php $subscriber = json_decode($this->subscriber); ?>
```

I am displaying all the  elements as

```
     <?php echo $subscriber->date; ?>
```

Where as now I want to display the date. When I directly display the date I am getting the format as `2014-07-15 17:02:50`

But I want to display in the format 15-07-2014. What are the functions used and how the code should be written in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHPs [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php) class to do it the OO way:

```
$dt = new DateTime($subscriber->date);
echo $dt->format('d-m-Y');
```

Or you can convert the date first from string to a unix timestamp using [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and then format it with the `date()` function as Vijayaragavendran mentioned in his answer:

```
echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime( $subscriber->date));
```

Comment: Lol looks like you made a similar typo in your update... `y` :)

Answer (score 3):

by  using date() function

```
date('d-m-y',strtotime( $subscriber->date))
```